# Como mandar un valor único c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

tengo tiempo fuera de el código y bueno, estoy retomando de nuevo con c# entity framework, tengo una duda en estos momentos, quiero saber como pasar un solo valor . ( en este caso es solo ciudadMaxima )

tengo mi controlador

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Ciudad> ciudades = db.Ciudades.ToList();
        List<Barrio> barrios = db.Barrios.ToList();
        List<Casa> casas = db.Casas.ToList();

        int CantidadCiudad = ciudades.Count();
        int CantidadBarrio = barrios.Count();
        int CantidadCasa = casas.Count();

        List<object> ciudadesConCasas = new List<object>(); 
        List<string> ciudadMaxima= new List<string>();
        int numerocasas = 0;
        int numeromaximo = 0;
        string nombreMaximo;


        foreach (Ciudad ciudadn in ciudades)
        {   
            List<Barrio> ciudadpocourbanizada = db.Barrios.Where(n => n.Fk_Ciudad == ciudadn.Id_Ciudad).ToList();
                foreach(Barrio CiudadesPocoOrganizadas in ciudadpocourbanizada)
            {
                List<Casa> hogar = db.Casas.Where(n => n.Fk_Barrio == CiudadesPocoOrganizadas.Id_Barrio).ToList();
                foreach(Casa hogares in hogar)
                {
                    numerocasas = numerocasas + 1;
                }
            }

            if (numerocasas >= numeromaximo)
            {
                numeromaximo = numerocasas;

                nombreMaximo = ciudadn.Nombre;
                ciudadMaxima.Add(nombreMaximo);

            }

        }

        ViewBag.ciudadMaxima = ciudadMaxima;
        ViewBag.ciudadesConCasa = ciudadesConCasas;

        ViewBag.CantidadCiudad = CantidadCiudad;
        ViewBag.CantidadBarrio = CantidadBarrio;
        ViewBag.CantidadCasas = CantidadCasa;


        return View();
    }
```

y en mi vista hago esto

```
        <tr>
        <td>
            @ViewBag.ciudadesConCasa
        </td>
        <td>
            @ViewBag.ciudadMaxima
        </td>
    </tr>
```

, pero solo me muestra el vector completo de donde traigo la información.

creo que es una pregunta tonta, pero de verdad estoy MUY fuera de practica, gracias a todos los que puedan ayudar de antemano.

Comment: Como ciudadMaxima es una lista, debes recorrerla con for en tu vista para obtener cada registro

Comment: No se trabaja de esa forma con entity framework, deberias relacionar las entidades, creo que deberias leer un poco mas de EF. Eso de definir 3 foreach para contar es una pesima implementacion.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas `Entity Framework` se supone que relaciones las entidades, pensemos que no lo hiciste cuando mapeas las entidades, bueno puedes hacerlo en el `linq` cuando armas la consulta.

Primero debes definir una clase en el `Model` de `asp.net mvc`

```
public class CiudadMaxima
{
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public string cantidad {get;set;}
}
```

Para despues poder armar el query de linq

```
var result = from ciudad in db.Ciudades
                join barrio in db.Barrios on barrio.Fk_Ciudad == ciudadn.Id_Ciudad
                join casa in db.Casas on case.Fk_Barrio == barrio.Id_Barrio
                group ciudad by ciudad.Nombre into g
            where g.Count() >= numeromaximo
            select new CiudadMaxima()
            {
                Nombre = g.Key,
                cantidad = g.Count()
            };

ViewBag.ciudadMaxima  = result;
```

el cual renderizas iterando las respuestas

```
<table ..>
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.ciudadMaxima){
  <tr>
     <td>@item.Nombre</td> 
     <td>@item.cantidad</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```